# Как узнать наименавание элемента xml в sql server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

У меня есть колонка в таблице, которая содержит данные в виде xml (тип данных колонки varchar(max) - поменять тип на xml нельзя)

Пример xml:

```
<diff>
    <Status>
        <old>1</old>
        <new>2</new>
    </Status>
    <Source>
        <old>307</old>
    </Source>
    <Home>
        <old>23</old>
        <new>12</new>
    </Home>
</diff>
```

Как я могу получить такую таблицу?

| ElementName |
| --- |
| Status |
| Source |
| Home |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @t table (x varchar(max))
insert into @t (x) values ('<diff>
    <Status>
        <old>1</old>
        <new>2</new>
    </Status>
    <Source>
        <old>307</old>
    </Source>
    <Home>
        <old>23</old>
        <new>12</new>
    </Home>
</diff>');

declare @xml xml;
SET @xml = (select cast(x as xml) from @t);

/*
declare @xml xml = '<diff>
        <Status>
            <old>1</old>
            <new>2</new>
        </Status>
        <Source>
            <old>307</old>
        </Source>
        <Home>
            <old>23</old>
            <new>12</new>
        </Home>
    </diff>'
 */  
    select distinct 
        n.c.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') as nodename
    from @xml.nodes('//diff/*') n(c)
```